# are there collection classes for .net which allow ref return values?

Tags: .net, optimization, collections, pass-by-reference, c#-7.0

I want to have a list of larger values types (e.g. vectors or matrices) and want to access them [by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/ref-returns) like this:

```
collection[index].X = newvalue;
```

or

```
ref Vector v = collection[index];
v.X = newvalue;
```

This syntax is allowed starting with C# 7.0, by I do not know if any collection classes already supports it. I know that vanilla arrays allows ref-access, but I need a collection.

Answer (score -1):

All class types are ref by default. which means if you modify class any where it will be refelcted where ever you access to it.

For example,

```
List<Test1> col=new List<Test1>(); // add list of objects
foreach(var testobj in col)
{
testobj.anyproperty= updatevalue; // this will update in collection also
}
```

Comment: The question is about value types (like structs).